# If each term in a sum of positive integers divides that sum, then there must be one term that divides another.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, induction

Let $\begin{align} \{ x_i  \}_{i=1}^n \end{align}$ be a finite sequence such that $x_i\in\mathbb{N}$. Prove that if $x_i$ divides $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$, $\forall{ 1\le i\le n}$ then there are $1\le j\neq h\le n$ such that $x_j$ divides $x_h$.
I know that I should avoid asking questions without trying to solve on my own, but I don't know where to start - I tried with induction but except the basis case of $n=2$. I couldn't reach anything.

> Let $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_1|(x_1+x_2)$ and $x_2|(x_1+x_2)$ so $\exists k_1,k_2$ such that $$k_1\cdot x_1=x_1+x_2 \implies (k_1-1)\cdot x_1=x_2\implies x_1|x_2 \\k_2\cdot x_2=x_1+x_2\implies(k_2-1)\cdot x_2=x_1\implies x_2|x_1\\ \Longrightarrow x_1=x_2 $$

Probably induction won't help, but I also thought that maybe the pigeonhole principle might come in handy, but could not think about anything.
Please help

Comment: Not sure it helps, but there are examples of such sequences for all $n$ with entirely distinct terms.  Indeed, taking  the first $n$ terms of $\{1, 2, 3, 6, 12, 24, \cdots\}$ (each term after $2$ being the sum of all prior terms) works.  Of course multiples of that work as well.

Comment: It's good to know, thank you! But I want to prove it works for every sequence!

Comment: Oh, of course, but I wasn't even sure such sequences could be designed (other than trivialities, like constant sequences).

Comment: @lulu FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x_j%5Cmid%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn%7Dx_i%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24x_j%5Cmid%20x_h%24&p=2), I found the related [Is it possible to find 2014 distinct positive integers whose sum is divisible by each of them?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3143024/602049).

Comment: @JohnOmielan Oh, thank you!  Nothing special about $2014$, of course.

Comment: Please don't use $\forall$ other than in formal logical expressions. It is much more readable to say "for all" (and in this case might have encouraged you to say it before rather than after the statement "$x_i$ divides ...$ which would have made it much easier to read).

Comment: Note that, if any $x_i$ are repeated, the requested condition is automatically met. Thus, assume they are all distinct, and $S=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$. Since $x_i\mid S$, this means for $n\gt 1$ that the set of $x_i$ are some, or all, of the proper factors of $S$, with them summing to $S$. This is the definition of [Semiperfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiperfect_number) (as the Wikipedia article says, they are also called pseudoperfect numbers).

Comment: Waiting for a proof for this problem. My current conjecture is that the smallest one divides another because I haven't found a counterexample of it. Moreover, it may be helpful if you divide both sides by the sum and you will get an equality that the sum of several reciprocals is equal to 1.

Comment: @ImbalanceDream You are saying that your conjecture is that if it's true then the smallest integer $x_i$ is the one was divides some other integer $x_j$?

Comment: @Chessplayer are you sure it's true? where did you get the problem?

Comment: @mathworker21 I am 95% it's true! If this is proven then it just might help me to prove a conjecture that has been assumed to be true for the past few decades.

Comment: @ImbalanceDream The conjecture about the _smallest_ integer necessarily dividing some other in the list fails for $(4,5,6,15,30)$.

Comment: Could you tell us the source of the problem?

Comment: @user I wrote it in the comment section already

Comment: I don't see it. Besides the rules require to write the motivation in the body of the question, not in the comment section.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but there aren't any rules. just accepted dictatorship(As people on discord say). Anyways, I am trying to prove a conjecture that is very assumed to be true, but not prove, and if I'll prove the question I asked here, it will very much likely help me to prove the first conjecture(which I don't want to say which one bc of obv reasons)

Comment: @Chessplayer so apparently the conjecture is false, I updated my answer with reference, but not sure if it notifies you when I edit answer so I thought I'd ping you in the comments as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update:

This conjecture is false - note that it is equivalent to [this conjecture](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4821709/1210477), which was disproved by Nechemia Burshtein (See [Example 2 after Question 6 here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X73901362) - Thanks to Lucid in the comments section of the other question for providing another reference that led to this.)

---

Note that to see the two conjectures are equivalent, we can observe that $x_j\mid \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ for each $j$ if and only if $y_j:=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{x_j}$ is an integer, in which case we have $$\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{y_j}=\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{x_j}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}=1,$$ and then $x_j\mid x_k$ if and only if $y_k\mid y_j$.

---

Original remark:

Here is an observation (too long for a comment, and actually leading to an answer for small $n$.)

> **Lemma.** The conjecture is true whenever $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}{x_k}$ has only one distinct prime factor for some $k$.

**Proof.**

Suppose $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i=p^mx_k$, for some prime $p$ and some $m$.  Let $p^l$ be the largest power of $p$ such that $p^l\mid x_k$.  If the conjecture fails, then for each $j\neq k$ we have $x_j\nmid x_k$ but $x_j\mid p^mx_k$, so we must have $p^{l+1}\mid x_j$, as otherwise multiplication by a power of $p$ will not change divisibility of $x_k$ by $x_j$.  Since $p^{l+1}\nmid x_k$, we then have $p^{l+1}\nmid \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$, contradicting $p^{l+1}\mid x_j\mid \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ when $j\neq k$.

> **Corollary.** The conjecture is true for $n\leq 6$.

**Proof.**

Let $x_k$ be the largest value.  With no loss of generality every other number is strictly smaller, so we have $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}{x_k}<\frac{nx_k}{x_k}=n\leq 6,$$ so $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}{x_k}$ has only one distinct prime factor.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?  I realize its a relatively small piece of the puzzle but thought it might be worth contributing?

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted, but where did you get the 6 from? why $n\le 6$?

Comment: @Chessplayer $6$ is the largest number where everything strictly less than it has only one prime factor.

Comment: I'm with you at $p^{l+1}$ does not divide $x_k$. How does that mean $p^{l+1}$ does not divide $\sum x_i$, which has a factor of $p^{l+m}$?

Comment: @SuhailSherif $p^{l+1}$ divides $\sum_{i\neq k}x_i$, so if it also divides $\sum x_i$, then it divides the difference of those two numbers, which is $x_k$.

Comment: It would be interesting to find an example such that $S/x_i$ is not a prime power for all $x_i$. There seems to be no such example for $S<400$.

Comment: @MW I dont see prove for question 3 there!

Comment: @Chessplayer updated with direct link to counter-example now.

Comment: The example in the paper yields a counterexample with $n = 68$ terms. I wonder what the smallest possible $n$ is.

Comment: @MW Please look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4827170/if-each-term-in-a-sum-of-positive-integers-with-gcdx-i-x-j-neq1-divides-th

Answer (score 4):

Too long for a comment (but not a complete solution):

Consider the case $n=3$.  We assume the three natural numbers $a,b,c$ are distinct (else the problem is trivial).  Without loss of generality take $a<b<c$.

We claim that $(a,b,c)$ is a multiple of $(1,2,3)$.  To see this, note that $a+b<2c$ yet $c$ divides $a+b$, so $a+b=c$.  Similarly, $2a<a+b=c<2b\implies a+c<3b$ But since $b\,|\,(a+c)$ we must have $a+c=2b$.  Combining this we see that $2a=b$ and $3a=c$, as desired.

Conjecture: The only examples of these sequences (with distinct terms) consist of multiples of the first $n$ terms of $ A=\{1,2,3, 6, 12, 24, 48, \cdots\}$ where the infinite sequence is defined by $A[1]=1, A[2]=2, A[n]=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}A[i]$ for $n>2$.  Of course, that establishes the desired result (though it remains to be proven, and, of course, it might not even be true).

Update I:  A commenter (@JohnOmielan) has produced counterexamples to my (admittedly over optimistic) conjecture.  For $n=4$, he found $1,4,5,10$ and for $n=5$, he found $1, 3,5,6,15$. As he remarks, the largest term in both of these is indeed the sum of the prior ones, but there is no particular reason to imagine that even this holds for all examples.  I add that these examples are "non-inductive", by which I mean that deleting the largest term does not produce a sequence of the form we want.

Update II:  A second commenter (@CalvinLin) produced $2,5,6,12,15,20$ which fails even the weaker notion (that the largest term should be the sum of the others).  I think that puts the final stake in the heart of the over-optimistic conjecture.

Comment: I see your point, but I don't get why would I need proof for $n=3$ when I need to prove it for $n\in\mathbb{N}$  - the general case.

Comment: @Chessplayer  It's always good to prove what you can.  If you can't do the whole thing at once, break it into pieces.  But, of course, if you have better ideas, you should pursue those.

Comment: The conjecture you wrote, did you think about it or is it a famous conjecture? If so, what is it's name?

Comment: It's original, for whatever it's worth.  And, to stress:  it might well be wrong.  "conjecture" might be too strong a term..."idea" might be better.   I'm not working on this any more, but if I were I'd try to establish the conjecture for $n=4$, or find a counterexample.  Either would be interesting (though I'd prefer to see the conjecture hold, of course).

Comment: Can you atleast tell me why you think this conjecture is true?

Comment: Because I can't come up with any other sequences that work and it's true for $n=3$.  As I say, counterexamples would be interesting as well.  Nature of problem solving, try various things, you usually learn useful things even if your idea is wrong.

Comment: I am trying to start a bounty on the question, but I can't find the key to start it, where is it?

Comment: It should be under the comments section.  It says "start a bounty".

Comment: @Chessplayer FYI, as stated in the network's Meta FAQ [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067) answer, "A bounty can be started on any question *48 hours* after the question was asked, provided the question isn't closed, locked, or deleted", with the emphasis being mine. The next paragraph gives basic instructions, with the initial part being "To start a bounty, click on the "Start a bounty" link at the bottom of an eligible question. (The link is underneath the comments, not in the 'post menu' like "Share" and "Edit".) The bounty panel will open. ...".

Comment: @JohnOmielan Yes, I'm blind and I ready eligable in 2 days as eligable until 2 days RIP

Comment: Although you wrote "I'm not working on this any more", FYI, there are counter-examples to your hypothesis. With $n=4$, there's $1+4+5+10=20$, and for $n=5$ there's $1+3+5+6+15=30$. Note, though, in both of my counter-examples, the largest value is the sum of all of the previous values, which your conjecture also states, but I doubt this will always hold either. Nonetheless, if you're interested, I'll let you know if I do come up with counter-examples to even that rather restrictive conjecture.

Comment: @JohnOmielan  Thanks!  Yeah, it seemed a bit over optimistic to imagine that the $n=3$ pattern held forever.  I note that your counterexamples aren't "inductive", meaning that dropping the largest term does not yield a "good" sequence.  That's not surprising, but a bit unfortunate.

Comment: Counter example to latest conjecture: 2, 5, 6, 12, 15, 20 for a sum of 60.

Comment: @CalvinLin  Thanks!  On balance, not a great set of conjectures, it would seem.

Comment: @lulu Can I tag a person so that he would see the question? If so, how?

Comment: Just as you did there.  @UserName. Can only tag one person per comment.