# Conjecture: If $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_i}=1$ then $x_i | x_j$

Tags: number-theory, conjectures, egyptian-fractions

Let $x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots , x_n\in\mathbb{N}$ prove that if $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{x_i}=1$, then there exist $x_j,x_i$ such that $x_j | x_i$.
I read that I should avoid the no clue questions, but this is a conjecture I came up with and need to know if it's true to continue my work on some project.

All I could figure out is that it's true for $n=2$ - and then $x_1=x_2=\frac{1}{2}$

## Edit

The user @deif proved the conjecture if there exist atleast one $x_i$ which is prime.
So to prove the conjecture entirely(if it's true) we just need to prove it with the assumption that $x_1,x_2,\cdots ,x_n$ are not primes!

Comment: It is also true for $n=3$ looking at $\frac12+\frac13+\frac16$ or $\frac12+\frac14+\frac14$ or $\frac13+\frac13+\frac13$

Comment: FWIW This is equivalent to [this problem posted yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4820935/prove-there-are-at-least-two-integers-that-divide-each-other/4820967?noredirect=1#comment10260745_4820967), with a suitable reskinning.

Comment: What does FWIW mean @CalvinLin

Comment: For What Its Worth.

Comment: Just as an observation, if there is some $x_i$ prime then the conjecture is easy to prove.

Comment: @CalvinLin How can you write something other then the URL - I can't find it! And why are they equivalent? I don't see it. I see why if my conjecture is true then it is proof for their question, but not the other way around

Comment: @Moaoly Multiply $\sum\frac{1}{x_i}=1$ by $\prod x_i$. Then reorder and factor.

Comment: @Deif Do you think you can explain it further and do the "hard work"? I don't think I see your point, and it might just help me out here.

Comment: @CalvinLin Just tagging you so that you'd see the previous comment

Comment: does this help? https://www.researchgate.net/publication/334721075_On_Distinct_Integers_the_Sum_of_Whose_Reciprocals_Equals_1_2_3

Comment: @CalvinLin Please explain the equivalence

Comment: @Moaoly See Deif's comment.

Comment: @CalvinLin Dief's comment explain why one prime proves the conjecture

Comment: @Moaoly It's the same idea. From their version of $ x_i \mid \sum x_i$, let $ A = \sum x_i$, and dividing throughout by A, we have $ \sum x_i/A = 1$. Their $x_i/A = 1/ X_i$, where this $X_i$ corresponds to yours.

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes, I proved like this too THANK YOU

Comment: @Lucid thanks for link, helped quite a bit!

Answer (score 5):

After following Lucid's link in the comments, we have [this reference](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X73901362), (see Example 2 in answer to Question 6), which indicates the conjecture is in fact false.

Answer (score 3):

(This is just a partial answer, but too long for a comment).
In case there is some $x_i$ prime we proceed as it follows. Without loss of generality we assume $x_1$ is prime.
Since
$$1=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{x_i},$$
multiplying by $\prod_{j=1}^nx_j$ we obtain
$$\prod_{j=1}^nx_j=\prod_{j=1}^nx_j\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{x_i}=\sum_{i=1}^n\prod_{\substack{j=1\\ j\not=i}}^nx_j.$$
Hence, solving and taking common factor $x_1$,
$$x_1(\prod_{j=2}^nx_j-\sum_{i=2}^n\prod_{\substack{j=2\\ j\not=i}}^nx_j)=\prod_{j=2}^nx_j.$$
Then, since $x_1$ is prime it must divide some $x_j$, where $2\leq j\leq n$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Accidentally accepted it last night and havnt noticed